# Парсинг контента <div> с помощью phpQuery

Tags: парсер, html, phpquery

Добрый день!
Есть определенный контент:

```html
<body>
{other content}
//begin my content
 <div id="list" class="vertical" class="list_top">
            <div did='304' class='draggable dev'><div class='dheader'><div class='dname' onclick='getDeviceInfo(this);'>(07597MK   ) Case 2388
             </div></div></div><div did='279' class='draggable dev'><div class='dheader'><div class='dname' onclick='getDeviceInfo(this);'>(07598MK   ) Case 2388
                                </div></div></div>
 </div>
//end my content
{other content}
</body>
```

мне нужно вытащить массив значений did=? и dname=?. В данном примере должен получить:
 1. did=304 dname= (07597MK   ) Case 2388
 2. did=279 dname= (07598MK   ) Case 2388
пытался сделать так:

```html
$pg = \phpQuery::newDocument($content);
            $elements = $pg->find('#list');
            $text = $elements->html(); //выводим весь список list
            
 foreach ($elements as element)
 {
    $did=pq($element)->find('did');
    $did=pq($did)->var();
    $dname=pq($element)->find('dname');
    $dname=pq($dname)->text();
    
    echo $did + $dname;
 }
```

Но в результате кроме вывода самого блока list ничего нет.
Подскажите как правильно сделать?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: код исправил на такой
<code>
$divs = pq($contents)->find ('div');           
            foreach ($divs as $div)
            {
                $did= pq($div)->attr('did');                
                $dname= pq($div)->find('div.dname')->Text();                               
                $info[] = array(
                    'did' => $did,
                    'dname' => $dname
                );
            }
</code>
но теперь в результате получаю затроенный массив

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($elements as element)
- foreach ($elements as $element)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]